# Compare Sharepoint and Excel Data

Tags: power-automate

I have two data sources, which are Sharepoint and Excel. Inside my Excel file there is a phone number and a total bill for each number, and inside my sharepoint there is a phone number and section. What I want to do is summarize a report based on sections and calculate the total bills by section. The phone numbers for both files are different in format. After that, generate a new Excel file.

I have tried many times but didnt know how to finish it.

**Excel**

[image]

**SharePoint**

[image]

Comment: Sooooooo use PowerBi?

Comment: my boss doesn't want to use powerbi